# Lifetime of temporary storage in Twilio Functions

Tags: twilio

I want to know the lifetime of temporary storage in Twilio Functions. To be specific, I have the following two questions:

1. For a studio flow, are all run-function-widgets access the same temporary storage? e.g. using it as a cache so I can download data from an external link once only (for each incoming phone call)
2. For different incoming phone calls, are temporary storage shared (or possibly shared) between them? I want to store some temporary user-specific data in it. I want to ensure that they can not see each other's temporary storage for different incoming phone calls.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66756066/twilio-temporary-storage-in-a-twilio-function) is a similar question, but I don't think "the answer" answered the question.

I have read [this blog](https://www.twilio.com/blog/temporary-storage-twilio-functions) and it says "*For example, you might like to create a file with user-provided data and send it onto the next step in a flow based on your business needs*". I guess it means for different incoming phone calls, executions of flow have their own temporary storage, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers:

1. Temporary Storage is only available for the Twilio Function that created the temporary storage at the time that Function is invoked and running. Once the Function is done running, the temporary storage is no longer available.
2. See #1, you will need to store state outside Studio and Functions if you want data to persist data across Studio flows/Function invocations. Some example of doing this are using Twilio Sync or Airtable to persist data.

[The Joints Of The Contact Center: Twilio’s Sync API](https://www.twilio.com/blog/contact-center-joints-sync-api)

[Use Twilio Sync to create, read, update, delete persist data](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/quickstart/serverless-functions-use-twilio-sync-to-create-read-update-delete-persistent-data)

[Using Airtable as a database for your Twilio app](https://www.twilio.com/blog/airtable-database-read)

[Writing to Airtable from your Twilio app](https://www.twilio.com/blog/writing-airtable-sms)

Comment: Thank you very much! That is exactly what I need!